# Regexp to save pattern match into variable

Tags: tcl

what is wrong with below code

```
    if {[regexp "pattern" $line]} {
    set match [lindex $line 1]
         } else {
     set match 0 }
```

i am trying to search a pattern (along with other patterns) in a large file which is repeated multiple times, once pattern matches i am storing into a variable 'match' else i need to print the same variable as 0, problem is that once pattern matches there is only one value printing continuously

for ex:

line1 v

line2 5

pattern 10

i am getting output as 0 and if else statement is not there output is 0, i tried using lsearch also but output is the same

**updating the question:**
File has following content  -:

Line1: Start cmd here
Line2: Start list here
Line3: End list here
.
.
.
few lines
.
.
.
Line1: Regular cmd here
Line2: Regular list here
pattern: 10
Line3: End file here

```
    set x {}
    set y {}
    set z {}

    set f1 [open file r]
    while {![eof $f1} {
    gets $f1 f

    if {[regexp "Line1:" $f]} {
    set x [lindex $f 1]
    }

      if {[regexp "Line3:" $f]} {
      set y [lindex $f 2]
    }

         if {[regexp "pattern:" $f]} {
         set z [lindex $f 1]
         } else {
     set z 0
      }
       puts "$x $y $z"
       }

      close $f1
```

output should be:
Start list 0
Regular file 10

Comment: Did you make sure your RegEx is ok first?
You could check it via https://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/tcl/index.html e.g.

Comment: @Thrawn, i am not sure of how to use the link here

Comment: What is the expected output (`$x $y $z`) in each iteration?

Comment: @mrcalvin    
Start list 0  ;  
Regular file 10

Comment: This does not make sense: a) Your example is not an MCVE, because `f` is not defined (I can only guess that this is a list of lines obtained from the filepath `file`); b) there is no line with content "Regular file 10" in your example data. I'd like to see a script and test data that I can copy&paste and run locally, if that helps.

Comment: @mrcalvin
I have edited the script again, with the output required as above, for understanding purpose copy content in a file and use the above script for reading that file

Answer (score 0):

Did you check out the [`regexp`](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/regexp.htm#M12) options `-all` and, possibly, `-inline`?

```
set matches [regexp -all -inline $yourRegEx $line]
```

## Update

As Donal pointed out, you need to treat the output of `regexp -all -inline` as a list:

```
set matches [regexp -all -inline $yourRegEx $line]
if {![llength $matches]} {
    set matches 0
}
```

Comment: i tried that also but i got following error:
expected boolean value but got ""

Comment: Then you need to check the `llength` of the result to see if anything matched.

Comment: @DonalFellows, without -all -inline i am getting output, 
i need to print output as 10 if pattern matches or else 0
in my case i am either getting all 10's or all 0 's

Comment: @mrcalvin, it dint work for me, does it work if 'pattern' is always present in file? i am executing a chunk of code wherein all other lines repeat periodically except the pattern i'm referring to, so while i am getting values of all other lines , i need to print variable as 0 if there is no pattern in that group of lines ..does your output come to 0 if there is no pattern ?

Comment: "file", "group of lines", "pattern". I am lost, I am afraid. I suggest you update your question to include an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) incl. representative test data (lines), the actual regular expression, and the expected match(es).

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing obviously wrong with the code

```
if {[regexp "pattern" $line]} {
    set match [lindex $line 1]
} else {
    set match 0
}
```

and if the contents of `line` are `{pattern 10}` it does indeed set `match` to 10.

But there might be problems in the surrounding code, like the variable `line` not getting updated with new values for each line.

To read and search every line in a file ("myfile.txt" for this example):

```
set f [open myfile.txt]
while {[gets $f line] >= 0} {
    if {[regexp "pattern" $line]} {
        set match [lindex $line 1]
    } else {
        set match 0
    }
    if {$match != 0} {
        break
    }
}
close $f
```

In this code, once a match has been found, no more lines are read from the file. If one wants to find matches from several lines, each match can be added to a list.

Also, if "pattern" contains regex metacharacters, `regexp pattern pattern` will fail, like in

```
% set pattern abc
abc
% regexp $pattern $pattern
1
% set pattern ab*c
ab*c
% regexp $pattern $pattern
0
```

Comment: yes, my variable 'line'  is not getting updated with every search, i tried to unset it or set it to empty, can it be updated at some point?

Comment: Using 'break' did not work for me, however setting variable to 0 after printing into another file, reset the variable before printing again, Thanks!